# How to narrow down results of the Ansible find module?

Tags: find, ansible

Instead of using the Ansible [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) or [command](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) modules, I am trying to use the [find module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) to delete old backup directories and only keep the latest `n` backups. Currently, I use the following code to get a list of all the backup directories (so that in a second step I could delete the unwanted ones):

```
- find:
    paths: "/opt/"
    patterns: "backup_*"
    file_type: "directory"
```

Unfortunately, I don't see any way of narrowing down the resulting list of directories...

1. The find module doesn't seem to support sorting... can that be done in any way?
2. Does Ansible provide any means to manipulate a JSON list... to keep only `n` elements in a list and remove all others?

Has anyone successfully used the find module for similar purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort with `sort` filter

You can task first N elements of a list with `[:N]` syntax.

```
- find:
    path: "/tmp/"
    pattern: "file*"
  register: my_files

- debug: msg="{{(my_files.files | sort(attribute='ctime'))[:-3] | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Sort files by `ctime`, take all but last three elements, take only `path` attribute and form a list.

Comment: Are these commands `sort`, `map` and `list` documented anywhere? I get an error ""template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'"

Comment: also, the `[:-3]` doesn't really do anything... always the full list is printed

Comment: yes, http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters and http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html